How to connect in this API?
I am trying to connect in an API.
The client sent me 2 URLS ( Test and Prod), Parameter, Client ID, Subscription (Ocp-Appim-Subscription-Key Parameter) and Client Secret
I was trying using Anaconda + Python Jupyter Notebooks using the code below but it is not working ( I have never done this before, maybe there is a better way of using)
I am not sure if I was using the correct way to connect. Should I use any azure tools or other tools?
The Code:
import requests

# API endpoint
url = "https://apim-genericapi-test.azure-api.net/GenericAPI/v1/"

# Authentication details
subscription_key = "xxxxxxxx"
client_secret = "xxxxxxxxxx"
client_id = "xxxxxxxxx"

# Request headers
headers = {
    "Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key": subscription_key,
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
}

# Authentication payload
payload = {
    "client_id": client_id,
    "client_secret": client_secret,
    "grant_type": "client_credentials"
}

# Requesting access token
token_url = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/token"
try:
    token_response = requests.post(token_url, data=payload)
    token_data = token_response.json()
    access_token = token_data.get("access_token")
    if not access_token:
        print("Failed to retrieve access token.")
        print("Response:", token_data)
        print("Request:", token_response.request.body)  # Print request body for debugging
        print("Response status code:", token_response.status_code)  # Print response status code
        exit()
except Exception as e:
    print("Error occurred while fetching access token:", e)
    exit()

# Making authenticated API request
try:
    response = requests.get(url, headers={"Authorization": "Bearer " + access_token})
    response.raise_for_status()  # Raise an exception for 4xx or 5xx status codes
    print(response.json())  # Print or handle the response data as needed
except requests.exceptions.HTTPError as err:
    print("HTTP Error:", err)
except Exception as e:
    print("Error occurred while making API request:", e)


"not working" – how exactly? What is the problem? Any specific error? Please provide a stack trace.

I see that you set value for variable headers but you never use it. Please check

https://apim-genericapi-test.azure-api.net/GenericAPI/v1/ is just a base URL of the API. Shouldn't you call any specific endpoint?

I have made few modification to your code and added all the required headers while making the request to APIM endpoint. I agree with Vlad DX, you need to call a specific operation from the API like I am using below operation for testing purpose.

This operation gives me below output.

I am using given code to invoke the Echo API.
import requests

# API endpoint
url = "https://{apim-instance-name}.azure-api.net/echo/resource?param1=sample"

# Authentication details
subscription_key = "bd7b******1c1d04"
client_secret = "f-h8Q~*******rrLjbBM"
client_id = "52c**********818"

# Request headers
headers = {
    "Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key": subscription_key,
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
}

# Authentication payload
payload = {
    "client_id": client_id,
    "client_secret": client_secret,
    "grant_type": "client_credentials"
}

# Requesting access token
token_url = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant_id}/oauth2/token"
try:
    token_response = requests.post(token_url, data=payload)
    token_data = token_response.json()
    access_token = token_data.get("access_token")
    if not access_token:
        print("Failed to retrieve access token.")
        print("Response:", token_data)
        print("Request:", token_response.request.body)  
        print("Response status code:", token_response.status_code)  
        exit()
except Exception as e:
    print("Error occurred while fetching access token:", e)
    exit()
    
# Combine headers
combined_headers = {
    **headers,
    "Authorization": "Bearer " + access_token
}

# Making authenticated API request
try:
    response = requests.get(url, headers=combined_headers)
    response.raise_for_status()  
    print(response.json())  
except requests.exceptions.HTTPError as err:
    print("HTTP Error:", err)
except Exception as e:
    print("Error occurred while making API request:", e)

I am able to get the expected response.


I am surprised you've been given client_id and client_secret, but not resource. Normally, I would expect your authentication payload to look like this:
payload = {
    "client_id": client_id,
    "client_secret": client_secret,
    "grant_type": "client_credentials",
    "resource": resource
}

Otherwise, the bearer token is not going to contain the right audience (claims/etc.) so the JWT validation on the API Management side would be somewhat tricky.
Then, you are initializing the headers at the beginning of your code. It is better to move this piece of code down so that you can add the Authorization header as well:
headers = {
    "Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key": subscription_key,
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    "Authorization": "Bearer " + access_token
}

Finally, make sure you are using the correct API endpoint - just in case https://apim-genericapi-test.azure-api.net/GenericAPI/v1/ is indeed just a base URL (the full URL might look like https://apim-genericapi-test.azure-api.net/GenericAPI/v1/operation_name). It's possible that your endpoint is correct as it is, but it's worth double-checking.
Other than these 3 potential issues, your code seems to be fine.
